# Issue on Getting URL of Uploaded Image to a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, attachments

I have a CPT called books and I am able to loop through it like this but I need to get the URL of the uploaded images into the post (not in Gallery). I tried to use WP `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` as bellow but I do not know what should I pass for `$attachment_id` as it is required

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'books',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'romance'
        )
    )
)
);
while ($loop->have_posts()):
    $loop->the_post();
  $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src('', 'full' );
   if ( $image_attributes ) : ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>" />
<?php endif; 
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Apparently this is not returning any of images uploaded to the CPT URL. Can you please let me know what I am missing and doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `get_post_thumbnail_id` and pass `$post->ID` in `wp_get_attachment_image_src` for e.g.

```
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
```

to get image url : `$image_attributes[0]`